# Qt GIF creation: Colours swapped when using gif-h library

Tags: c++, c, qt, graphics, gif

Apparently, I am trying to use [gif-h](https://github.com/charlietangora/gif-h) library for gif creation with qt 4.7 for a C++ project. After embedding the library to the project, I can generate GIF through my qt GUI app, however, the colours on the final/actual GIF are swapped. What I mean is that: 
below red frame 
[image: image1] 
becomes below blue frame 
[image: image2]
and same goes for other way round (i.e. blue frame becomes red frame).

Just like above, below orange frame 
[image: image3]
becomes below sky blue frame 
[image: image4]
and same goes for other way round (i.e. sky blue frame becomes orange frame).

Could someone familiar with the library or graphics or gif creation in code guide me?

I am happy to provide more information about image capturing and such, as and when needed.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: From the description you have the red/blue parts of you colours swapped.

Comment: It seems like a RGB-BGR issue. Depending on libraries, the convention may be RGB or BGR (which would explain the red/blue inversion)

Comment: You should provide a minimal example, should be an easy fix, as @Fareanor pointed out the problem is in the format. QImage has property for that.

Comment: In the interest of eyeball preservation, please edit your question and put any relevant code there.

Comment: I have updated the question to provide code example of image grabbing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have managed to resolve the problem by using QImage::rgbSwapped() function. Thank you to @Pablo Yaggi particularly for the hint.

I will have to remove the code snippet from the question due to security reasons.